# Keep item at same monitor position regardless of window size/position

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am trying to create a game with fullscreen.

When I add an object to the `stage` in full screen mode, I would like it to stay at the same coordinates (for example 1000 pixels) relative to the **monitor** when I exit fullscreen mode.

How can I make the object move to the same location when leaving fullscreen mode?

Comment: I don't understand your question.   Are you saying you want the item to stay in same relative position (to the monitor) regardless of window position/size?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant

Comment: This is a fairly involved question (though certainly do-able).  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your started:

Something along these lines is what you'll need to do:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;  //you'll need to running a top-left no-scale swf for this to work
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

var itemPoint:Point = new Point(150,150);  //the point on the monitor the object should reside

//call this anytime the item needs to be redrawn (eg when the window changes size or position)
function updatePos(e:Event = null){
    //We need to also account for the chrome of the window 
    var windowMargin:Number = (stage.nativeWindow.bounds.width - stage.stageWidth) * .5; //this is the margin or padding that between the window and the content of the window
    var windowBarHeight:Number = stage.nativeWindow.bounds.height - stage.stageHeight - windowMargin; //we have to assume equal margin on the left/right/bottom of the window

    item.x = itemPoint.x - stage.nativeWindow.x - windowMargin;
    item.y = itemPoint.y - stage.nativeWindow.y - windowBarHeight;
}

stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.MOVE, updatePos); //we need to listen for changes in the window position
stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZE, updatePos); //and changes in the window size

//a click listener to test with
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:Event):void {
    if(stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE){
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
    }else{
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
    }
});

updatePos();
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this line of code does?

Comment: stage.displayState = (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE ? StageDisplayState.NORMAL : StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE);

Comment: That just toggles full-screen mode.   It's an inline if statement.    So if the current displayState is fullscreen, assign it `normal`, otherwise, assign it `full screen interactive`.   I edited the question to make it a regular if statement if that helps (they do exactly the same thing)

Comment: I understand it much better with the if statement. Thanks alot